# A LINQ with XML question

Tags: c#, linq

How can I use LINQ to retrieve a specific value of **Supported** attribute nased on the condition **URL="localhoist"**? Thank you.

```
<SomeSetting>
  <Setting URL="abc.com" Supported="sb.new,mgrsma" />
  <Setting URL="localhost" Supported="GG,LLmgrsma,FF1,FF3" />
  <Setting URL="def.zxy.com" Supported="xyz" />
</SomeSetting>
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
var localhost = doc.Descendants("Setting")
                   .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("URL") == "localhost")
                   .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("Supported"))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

One line at a time:

- First select all the "Setting" elements; you could also do this using `someSetting.Elements("Setting")` where `someSetting` is the `SomeSetting` element
- Add a where clause to filter out elements which don't have a URL of localhost. I'm using the explicit string conversion rather than the `Value` property so that it copes with elements without the `URL` attribute; in that case the conversion will return null
- Select the `Supported` attribute value - again, this will return null if a `URL=localhost` element has no `Supported` attribute.
- Select the first result, or null if there were no results. If you may have multiple elements and want to examine all of them, just remove this call.